# What is the correct way to present the disks to ASM?

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-12c, installation, disk-structures

Hello I would like to know which is the correct way ... or the most recommended way to present the disks to ASM, for example: I have 3 disks mapped to a server (rhel7) orasys, orafra, oradata, with dm-multipath I configure the multipath and I put aliases (orasys, orafra and oradata respectively). The doubt I have from there, I have read in the guides, that the disks are formatted, leaving for examples: orasys1, orafra1, oradata1 and these are the ones that are presented to ASM as /dev/mapper/* and with the respective permissions ... but when I do it that way it gives an error finishing the installation of the grid because it cannot create the diskgroup, however if I do not format them, that is, I present them directly as orasys, orafra and oradata I have no problem.
The database is oracle 19c and I don't use asmlib but udev rules.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How did you "format" them? Oracle expect them to be block devices, not formatted with a file system. Did you read this documentation?

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/configuring-device-persistence-manually-for-oracle-asm.html#GUID-70D50812-CCB2-41E4-AA3B-4689E1DA934E
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/udev-scsi-rules-configuration-in-oracle-linux#load_updated_block_device_partitions"
- https://dba010.com/2019/07/22/udev-rules-for-configuring-asm-disks/
- https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-set-udev-rules-for-asm-on-multipath-disks/